# Function specified in onclick not firing on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a webpage which should work on both desktop and mobile devices. I'm having quite a bit of trouble making the buttons work, however.

This is how a button looks like:

```
 <a class="button" id="upload-media-button" onclick='uploadMedia();'>Upload</a>
```

And this is the `uploadMedia` code:

```
var uploadMedia = function() {

if(!isUploadFormVisible){
    alert(isUploadFormVisible);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    dropperForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
    dropperForm.className = '';
    isUploadFormVisible = 1;
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");

} else {
    alert(isUploadFormVisible);
    event.preventDefault();
    dropperForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
    dropperForm.className = 'hidden';
    isUploadFormVisible = 0;
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
    refreshMedia(true);
}

}
```

The funny thing is that the buttons work fine on desktop and it partially works on mobile as well (if instead of `onclick='uploadMedia();` I do `onclick='alert(whatever);` the alert is displayed successfully). I've spent most of yesterday and today trying to fix the issue, but it is simply not working.

I've tried something like this as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#upload-media-button').on('click touchstart', function(){
    dropperForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
    dropperForm.className = '';
    isUploadFormVisible = 1;
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");

});
}
```

And this still doesn't work.

Edit:

Even though the answer helped me fix the issue, it was only a momentary fix: this was absolutely unbelievable and I was really confused on how to make those damn buttons work. I had tried everything.

By investigating the issue, I found out that this problem never appeared on desktop (with both static file compression off and on), however, on mobile, compression did make a difference as without it it worked fine.

The conclusion to this investigation is clear: **check your code for syntax errors**. I was missing maybe a dozen semicolons and the console didn't complain whatsoever (in fact it worked ok on desktop w/ compression).

Anyways, if you use compression like me, make sure to grab the source from the compressed file and run it through JSHint (or whatever works for you), to check for syntax errors.

Now I get why people hate JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `<a>` tag with no `href` attribute is not a tap target for touchscreens.

Add `href="#"` (with a suitable `event.preventDefault();` call) or `href="javascript:void(0);"` to make it an actual, clickable (tappable) thing.